# Sphinx: batch query in sphinxQL

Tags: c#, sphinx, sphinxql

I am using sphinx search engine for full text search and I want to send several search queries to searchd deamon in one batch. I know that it's possible in SphinxAPI, but I want to use this feature in SphinxQL.I have read from Sphinx documnetation that :

> Starting version 2.0.1-beta, SphinxQL supports multi-statement
>   queries, or batches ... (Ref:[+](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/sphinxql-multi-queries.html))

so my questions are:

1) How can I use this feature in SphinxQL? Is it enough to separate select statement with ';' and by this method they are considered in one batch?

2) How can I use this feature in SphinxQL that connected with C# by using mysql library? (How to send multiple query and manage multiple result set?)

Comment: Its not really a feature of SphinxQL. SphinxQL defines format for a single query. So your first question is invalid. You are looking how to send multiple queries at once with your particular client library. which one using? https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.9.html maybe?

Comment: Yes, I use MySQL Connector/Net.

Comment: and about my first question you said that SphinxQL defines format for a single query, So if I want to use SphinxQL from command line how can I use that? I mean I want to send multiple query in one go from SphinxQL command line.

Comment: Would you please answer my question if you have any suggestion?

Comment: see the 'delimiter' command in the command line client https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html that controls multiple commands.  See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html (`Allow Batch`)